# AngularJS : directives nested in a ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have an angularjs web app which has a view with the following basic structure :

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="entry in entries" ng-switch on="entry.type" logic-options >
         <div ng-switch-when=1 text-entry></div>
         <div ng-switch-when=2 other-entry></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here text-entry and other-entry are directives which have there own templates and logic-options is another directive which has a template and controller.

The logic-options directive provides some functions to be used by the child scope and has replace: false so that it should append its template to the end of the li. The text-entry and other-entry directives simply have some templates to be inserted which are also used on other views.

When I run this the logic-options directive will render and seems to function but the inner directives (text-entry and other-entry) will not.

In the console I get the error :

```
Error: Argument '?' is required qa@...
```

What causes this error and how do I correct it?

A fiddle demonstrating this problem : http://jsfiddle.net/cubicleWar/c3mTT/1/

Comment: Do you have a plnkr or a fiddle that replicates the issue?

Comment: No, the problem is from a much larger code base. I will try to cut the code down into something more manageable and create a fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you should be transcluding the child elems, also you may want to avoid
putting 'ng-switch' directive in a different layer, so that it would not conflict with
other directives.

```
app.directive('logicOption', function() {
  return {
    replace: false,
    transclude: true,
    template: "<div ng-transclude>{{entry.type}} : This is the logic stuff</div>"
  };    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YusCU/

Comment: It seems that you must put the switch into another layer or it will not work.